# threejs lerp and camera the animation is not smooth

Tags: javascript, three.js

what is the problem with linear interpolation?
in update()  in case this is animate()
and when I call zoomCamera() in update() there is lerp with smooth
but when I call here

```
function onObjectsClick(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            setPickPosition(event);
            raycasting(pickPosition, scene, camera);
            pickedObject = intersectedObjects[0].object;
            const notebook = pickedObject.getObjectByName('notebook');
            const laptop = pickedObject.getObjectByName('laptop');

            if (notebook || laptop) {

                zoomCamera();
            }

        }
canvas.addEventListener('click', onObjectsClick, false);
```

in **if**
there is no smooth lerp but sharp transition
what I miss?

```
function zoomCamera() {
            const vec = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 2, 2);
            const alpha = .1;
            camera.position.lerp(vec, alpha);
            console.log('zoom');
        }
```

and the onObjectsClick is in animate()
why it is happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't include your `OnObjectsClick()` function inside your animation loop, this is going to make your system haywire because it will probably create 60 versions of the same function per second.

Also, don't create a new `THREE.Vector3` each time you call the `zoomCamera()` function. Instead, create one target, and have the camera constantly lerping towards that target in your animation loop. When you've detected a click, change the value of the camera's target position. Like this:

```
// Set camera to original position
var cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3(3, 4, 4);

// Click listener goes outside animation loop
function onObjectsClick(event) {

    // ...

    if (notebook || laptop) {
        // When conditions are met, change target position
        cameraTarget.set(-1, 2, 2);
    }

    // ...

}

animate() {
    // Camera will lerp closer to target on each frame
    camera.position.lerp(cameraTarget, 0.1);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```